# Console to Python log

Tags: javascript, python

I'm looking for a way get a console output from Google Chrome into my python program. I have a script coded in JS that finishes in around 1 second, but my python implementation (exactly same logic, etc, the only diff is that it's in Python and not JS) takes about 15 seconds to run. Therefore I'm looking for a way to get the printout in Chrome console to my python program.

This is the current way I'm doing it:

1. Python program uses pyautogui to click and does what it needs to do inside to trigger the function running in JS.
2. JS completes the function in 1s and prints to console, something like:

`(22) [6, 4, 4, 6, 0, 1, 1 2, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 4, 4, 6, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 6, 0]`

I would like to find a way to get this output into python as I have another script that takes the output and does stuff to it

Answer (score 0):

I think you might use Selenium to do that!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities    
# enable logging
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d)
# load your site
driver.get('http://example.com')
# print the messages
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print entry
```

Entries whose `source` field equals `'console-api'` correspond to console messages, and the message itself is stored in the `message` field.

Comment: How much time is spent opening through the webdriver? I would like to minimize the total runtime from beginnign to end (something like 2s)